# how put "bash color" to variables

Tags: bash

output of:

```
echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"
```

is

```
Hello World (red color)
```

so I'd like put: `\e[31m` to variable:

```
REDCOLOR="\e[31m"
```

and use it as:

```
echo -e "$REDCOLORusing red color"
```

Comment: As your question stands, there is no question. It is a statement?

Comment: Incidentally, all-uppercase names are conventional only for environment variables and builtins; using lowercase names everywhere else avoids unintentionally shadowing or overwriting an environment variable when you only mean to set a local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`
echo "${red}red text ${green}green text${reset}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `${REDCOLOR}` instead. As you wrote it, bash is trying too look at the variable named `REDCOLORusing` instead of `REDCOLOR`

Comment: ...this works _if_ you're willing to use `echo -e`, which isn't a good practice (providing `-e` is only possible if an `echo` implementation violates the POSIX standard!)

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html for the POSIX spec for `echo`, and particularly the "APPLICATION USAGE" note.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy certainly, but you will always need to put the variable names in curly braces no matter how you get the color red into a variable

Comment: Sure -- but that's not an issue specific to practices around saving color to variables... which is, after all, the title and focus of this question.

Answer (score 2):

The proper practice is to use `tput` to interrogate the appropriate escape sequences for your system:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
```

This returns the literal escape sequences to be sent to the terminal, rather than backslash-escape sequences describing them. Thereafter, you can use (with no `-e` argument):

```
echo "${red}using red${green}using green"
```

See [BashFAQ #37](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037).